# Two 'False' statements with different results MySQL

Tags: mysql

I have a Query that works Just fine until I add a single phrase tot he where clause.   I have set that phrase to:  **p.group_size <> 8772663552**  a ridiculous inequality.

This Query Fails to find the record for the record with the corresponding last name :Balasubramanian

```
SELECT DISTINCT p.id, 
               p.last_name, 
               first_name,
               corporate_name, 
               city, 
               state,         
               e.full_name, 
               type, 
              l.current_step, 
          l.current_step_date,
FROM   prospect AS p 
       LEFT OUTER JOIN lettherebelight l 
                    ON p.id = l.prospect_id 
       LEFT OUTER JOIN employee e 
                    ON p.id_ofproducer = e.id 
WHERE  p.group_size <> 8772663552 
       AND type IN ( 'Prospect', 'Suspect' ) 
       AND ( last_name LIKE 'Balasubramanian' 
              OR corporate_name LIKE 'Balasubramanian' 
              OR first_name LIKE 'Balasubramanian' )
```

But this one succeeds (note the single line difference)

```
SELECT DISTINCT p.id, 
               p.last_name, 
               first_name,
               corporate_name, 
               city, 
               state,
               e.full_name, 
               type, 
              l.current_step, 
          l.current_step_date,
FROM   prospect AS p 
       LEFT OUTER JOIN lettherebelight l 
                    ON p.id = l.prospect_id 
       LEFT OUTER JOIN employee e 
                    ON p.id_ofproducer = e.id 
WHERE  type IN ( 'Prospect', 'Suspect' ) 
       AND ( last_name LIKE 'Balasubramanian' 
              OR corporate_name LIKE 'Balasubramanian' 
              OR first_name LIKE 'Balasubramanian' )
```

Or if i change the line from **p.group_size <> 8772663552** to ***p.ID > 0*** It works just fine:

```
 SELECT DISTINCT p.id, 
                   p.last_name, 
                   first_name,
                   corporate_name, 
                   city, 
                   state,         
                   e.full_name, 
                   type, 
                  l.current_step, 
              l.current_step_date,
    FROM   prospect AS p 
           LEFT OUTER JOIN lettherebelight l 
                        ON p.id = l.prospect_id 
           LEFT OUTER JOIN employee e 
                        ON p.id_ofproducer = e.id 
    WHERE  p.ID > 0
           AND type IN ( 'Prospect', 'Suspect' ) 
           AND ( last_name LIKE 'Balasubramanian' 
                  OR corporate_name LIKE 'Balasubramanian' 
                  OR first_name LIKE 'Balasubramanian' )
```

Both  p.group_size <> 8772663552 to p.ID > 0  are both true.   Why would they produce different results? What am I missing?

Comment: . . They are both *false* so the id is always zero or less than zero?  I would think they are always true.

Comment: What datatype is p.group_size?

Comment: What do you mean by it doesn't "work" or that they are "false" are you getting an empty result set or are you getting errors?

Comment: @MikeBrant Read the second paragraph of the question.

Comment: @MikeBrant  Empty set  "Fails to find"

Answer (score 1):

I believe the reason is that `group_size` can take on a NULL value.  In this case, your expression is evaluated as NULL, which is treated as FALSE in a boolean context.

Comment: Any SQL tutorial should discuss them.

Comment: You are writing pretty advanced SQL for such a question.  I suppose the best thing to do is to write something like "Check for NULL values" on a yellow sticky, put it on your computer screen, and when you have a problem, follow the advice.  I (and most people) generally learn from their mistakes.  It just takes time.

Comment: @Barmar  AS per the reference  "Because the result of any arithmetic comparison with NULL is also NULL, you cannot obtain any meaningful results from such comparisons."   Thanks!